# Getting email to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a code that catch emails and put in a spreadsheet and put this email in other label, its working but I put the range between 0 - 50, when I look at the label to where emails are appearing more than 50 emails, why is this happening?

Thank you

code

```
function get_emails() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Fale Conosco/Contato');  
  var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Teste Done');

  var threads = label_pending.getThreads(0, 50); 

  var index = getColIndexByName('Conteúdo');

  for (var t in threads) {

    var thread = threads[t];

    var html = thread.getMessages()[0].getBody();
    html=html.replace(/<\/div>/ig, '\n');
    html=html.replace(/<\/li>/ig, '\n');
    html=html.replace(/<li>/ig, '  *');
    html=html.replace(/<\/ul>/ig, '\n');
    html=html.replace(/<\/p>/ig, '\n');
    html=html.replace(/<br\/?>/ig, '\n');
    html=html.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, '');

    sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow() + 1), index).setValue(html);

    thread.removeLabel(label_pending);  
    thread.addLabel(label_done);
  }
  return 0;
}  

function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i'm getting your question correctly, but you are dealing with threads and a thread could be composed by many email messages, so this could be the reason why you get a different number of messages

Comment: Thanks, it was just that I was getting a lot of emails now is one by one

Answer (score 0):

I fix its working now, i add a loop to see message by message

```
function processPending() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Fale Conosco/Contato');  
  var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Teste Done');

  var threads = label_pending.getThreads(0, 5);

  var index = getColIndexByName('Conteúdo');

  for (var t in threads) {

    var thread = threads[t];

    var messaqnt = thread.getMessages();

    for (var i in messaqnt) {

      var html = messaqnt[i].getBody();
      html=html.replace(/<\/div>/ig, '\n');
      html=html.replace(/<\/li>/ig, '\n');
      html=html.replace(/<li>/ig, '  *');
      html=html.replace(/<\/ul>/ig, '\n');
      html=html.replace(/<\/p>/ig, '\n');
      html=html.replace(/<br\/?>/ig, '\n');
      html=html.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, '');

      sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow() + 1), index).setValue(html);

      thread.removeLabel(label_pending);  
      thread.addLabel(label_done);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}  

function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to both answers, here is a script that handles the HTML to text conversion in a less 'trivial' way.

I used a code from [a post by Corey G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936092/remove-formatting-tags-from-string-body-of-email) that has the advantage (for me) to get the accented characters in french for example...(which is my use case ;-)

```
function get_emails() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('NoLabel');  

  var threads = label_pending.getThreads(0, 10); 
  var index = getColIndexByName('test');

  for (var t in threads) {
    var thread = threads[t];
    var msgcount = thread.getMessageCount()

   for(m=0;m<msgcount;++m){

  var html = thread.getMessages()[m].getBody();
  var txt = getTextFromNode(Xml.parse(html, true).getElement());
  sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow() + 1), index).setValue(txt);
}
  }
  return 0;
}  


function getTextFromNode(x) {
  switch(x.toString()) {
    case 'XmlText': return x.toXmlString();
    case 'XmlElement': return x.getNodes().map(getTextFromNode).join('');
    default: return '';
  }
}

function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1;
  }
```