# Google Apps Scripts - Extract data from gmail into a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, google-apps-script, gmail

this is the first script i try to write from scratch. It's been no good up to now so i'm going to ask for some help.

Case: I recieve e-commerce confirmation emails from e-commerce sites no reply email address. In the email's body they send email address from buyers. I want to send an automated mail to the body's email address.

How i plan to do this (any suggetions to eliminate steps will be thanked).

1. Use a rule to tag incoming emails with a unique tag.
2. Use that tag to identify emails in gmail with a script, go one by one and extract the info i need. Use regex with the emails body content to extract the email address i need to send the automated emails. Plan is to get: subject, date, email from body.
3. Write all that info to a spreadsheet.
4. Get rid of unique tag info to prevent duplicate runs.
5. Then use form mule addon to send emails from the spreadsheet.

So far, i've dealt with steps 1 (easy), and been stuggling with steps 2 and 3 (im not a coder, i can read, undestrand and hack. writing from scratch is a completely different thing). Ive dealt with 4 before i think this is the best way to deal with it.

With the script i extract info to the spreadsheet, with the addon i use the info from the spreadsheet to send emails.

This is the code ive written so far. I've left the regex part for later cause i cant even write anything into the spreadsheet yet. once i get that working, ill start working in the regex and "remove the label" aspects of the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  function getemails() {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Main tag/subtag");
    var threads = label.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { 
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();  
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
    var message=messages[j];
    var subject=message.getSubject();
    tosp(message);
      }
     }
  }

  function tosp(message){
    var body=message.getBody()
    var date=message.getDate();
    var subject=message.getSubject(); 
    var id= "my spreasheet id";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow(subject,date,body);    

}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Following is the code I wrote and tested that performs the steps 2, 3 and 4 mentioned by you perfectly well.

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var msg = messages[j].getBody();
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();

      ss.appendRow([msg, sub, dat])
    }
      threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

One of the faults in your code was that the `appendRow` function accepts an array of elements specified within `[ ]` brackets.

Depending on where you're attaching this script, your line of code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
```

is not necessary if the script is being written in the script editor of the Spreadsheet where you want these emails to be logged. However, if there are multiple sheets in that spreadsheet, you can replace my line

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

by

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

Another suggestion is that the current code will give you messages in HTML format. Hence, if you want to get the message in plain text as you see it, use:

```
var msg = messages[i].getPlainBody();
```

Now you can write another function for regex and pass the message `msg` to that. Hope this helps!

Comment: Such a nice and detailed explaination! I just could not pass by without giving Thumbs Up to 'pointNclick'!

Comment: @pointNclick, sorry old thread. but couldnt help replying....i have 5000+ messages (threads) in a label in gmail. but the above code only lists 524 messages into the google spreadsheet. Thread.length under debug mode shows only 500. what could be the reason?

Comment: @sifar, Google has an count and time limit. You can maneuver this by setting a variable such as lastthreadposition (as a getValue() from your sheet) and adding it with the for loop's increment counter, (like i++ && lastthreadposition++). After the loop, setValue() the new value. On next run pull threads as getThreads(lastthreadposition, 500). Set a time based trigger to repeat. I would suggest using a smaller interval than 500, such as 100 emails every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

I made a ready-to-use script, explaining how to use it (from the start) as well, for those who need more assistance.

It's on [gmail-to-google-sheets-script](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/gmail-to-google-sheets-script) repository. Just read the content and follow the instructions.

#### How to use

- Create a new Google Sheet
- Access menu Tools > Script Editor
- Copy the content from [gmailt-to-sheets.gs](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/gmail-to-google-sheets-script/blob/master/gmailt-to-sheets.gs) to editor, replacing the sample code there
- Replace the value on `SEARCH_QUERY` to your real query (Do your search on gmail first, copy and paste the search terms there)
- Select `saveEmails` on menu (near "run" and "debug" buttons)
- Click on "Run" button
- It will ask for authorization at first run, proceed accepting it (it's your Gmail account authorizing your Google Script account)
- After run, the results will be applied to you sheet

#### Changing fields

If you want to save different message attributes, take a look at [gmail-message class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) and change your script file the code below comments with a ✏️ (pencil).

Comment: Be aware your current code in the github repo is badly coded. Numbers don't match in the console, among other things. Thank you though for sharing. Your script gives results but without warranty of being accurate.

Comment: Thank @blitzter47 for your comment. But, could you be more specific? If it has some error, I won't try to fix it. It's not bullet proof solution for sure but seems to handle the need.