# GmailMessage getBody's HTML output is not very clean

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

Because Gmail's "canned responses" are not available from [Google Apps Script for Gmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/), I was trying the following:

1. Send the template email to myself (let's say its Subject is Template_238) with traditional Gmail interface
2. Load this email in Google Apps Script with [getBody](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody()):

   ```
   var mytemplate = GmailApp.search('Template_238').getMessages()[0];
   var body = mytemplate.getPlainBody();
   var htmlbody = mytemplate.getBody();
   ```
3. Then I can send it with:

   ```
   GmailApp.sendEmail("test@example.com", "Sending a template", body, {htmlBody: htmlbody});
   ```

But I noticed that getting the HTML body of an already-sent-by-gmail email gives a dirty result:

```
<div dir=3D"ltr"><div><span style=3D"font-size:12.8px">Hello,</span><br sty=
le=3D"font-size:12.8px"><br style=3D"font-size:12.8px"><span style=3D"font-=
size:12.8px">Thank you for contacting us.</span><br style=3D"font-size:12.8=
px"><br style=3D"font-size:12.8px"><span style=3D"font-size:12.8px">We have=
 received your inquiry and will contact you soon</span><br>=
</div><div><br></div><div><div class=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><=
div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div>Best regards,<br></div><div=
><br>Myself<br><br></div><div><b>Company</b><br></div><div><a hre=
f=3D"http://www.example.com" target=3D"_blank">www.example.com</a><=
br></div><div><a href=3D"http://www.facebook.com/example" target=3D"_bl=
ank">www.facebook.com/example</a><br><br><img src=3D"http://www.exam=
ple.com/logo.png"><br></div></div></div></div></div></div>=
</div></div></div>
```

I often see things like:

```
<div class=3D"gmail-m_681872521129xxx6703m_-59021xxx267255=
64285gmail-m_2008053448xxx413226gmail-m_-370479949603xxx4147gmail-m_5189037=
0070xxx5842gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"=
ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div style=3D"font-size:small"><div =
class=3D"gmail-m_681872521129xxx6703m_-59021828267xxxx64285gmail_signature">=
<div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr">
```

even if my input was just some text, with a few links and bold text here and there.

**Isn't there a cleaner way to get HTML of a mail with Google Apps Scripts for Gmail?** (i.e. without so many div, so many 8469832649732649gmail_signature).

Comment: Note that [`getBody()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody()) method will get body of the message in HTML format. So, if you need the content of the body of the message without HTML formatting, then try using [`getPlainBody()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getplainbody) method instead.

Comment: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890847/google-apps-scripts-extract-data-from-gmail-into-a-spreadsheet) and this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54670/send-html-email-from-a-spreadsheet-using-a-different-alias) for additional insights.

Comment: Thanks for these links @Teyam. Actually, I do want HTML body (and not only plain text), but I would like a cleaner HTML than thinks like `div class=3D"gmail-m_681872521129xxx6703m_-59021xxx267255=
64285gmail-m_2008053448xxx413226gmail-m_-370479949603xxx4147gmail-m_5189037=
0070xxx5842gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"=
ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div dir=3D"ltr"`. It's like gmail inserted lots of unwanted HTML tags!