# Extract Rows+Columns from gmail body to Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I want to extract the table structure data given in gmail body with tag 'GmailtoStudio' and save in spreadsheet in proper rows and columns.

An example email body is given in this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_yh8R4jiwM3QNMU3WyUaejSW3RG09WT/view?usp=sharing
[image]
So the script is supposed to copy data starting from "Client Time" columns from an email up to the last row and save it to spreadsheet in 12 columns.

I have managed following code using different support articles but it doesn't work yet;

```
function mailToStudio() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('GmailtoStudio');
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    var htmlbody = msg.getBody();
    var body = htmlbody.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/ig, " ");
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    activeSheet.appendRow([body]);
  }
}
```

There are two problems in this code:
1- It does not copy data in different columns. Instead it copies data in single cell.
2- I think the data copied in cell from email body also contains lots of code that looks like css code.

What changes should I do in this code to get the data right in spreadsheet. Or if it is not possible with this script, what is other script that can do the job right.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share an image of your email?

Comment: Have you ever considered asking the sender to attach a csv file to your email when it's created.  They already have the data so it would be easy to create a csv file and a lot easier to extract the data directly into the correct type of array.

Comment: Image shared now at top. Emails are automatic. Attachments not possible.

Comment: Well it looks like your code is just stripping html tags and nothing else.

Comment: Can you share the raw content of one of the emails.  You can get it in gmail by displaying the original.

Comment: I tried Regexp (/Client Time(\W|\w)*Total/gi) but it gives nothing in cell except [Ljava.lang.Object;@.....

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890847/google-apps-scripts-extract-data-from-gmail-into-a-spreadsheet

Comment: I just shared email snapshot. Yes I checked above topic already but it doesn't address my issue. (getPlainBody();) gives me "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"

Comment: That file only shows text.  There's no html in that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209884/discussion-between-abdul-and-mimi).

Comment: Can you share a sanitized sample of the email in HTML format?

Answer (score 0):

This function will put the table into your spreadsheet. I copied the data into a file first.  It turns out that it is just a tab separated file.

```
function loadFileIntoSS() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.clearContents();
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById('text file id');
  var rA=file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split('\n');
  rA.forEach(function(r,i){if(i>12 && i<113) {sh.appendRow(r.split('\t'));}});
}
```

So something like this might work for you.

```
function mailToStudio() {
  var label=GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('GmailtoStudio');
  var threads=label.getThreads();
  for (var i=threads.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    var msg=threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    var rA=msg.getBody().split('\n');
    var oA=[];
    rA.forEach(function(r,i){if(i>12 && i<113){oA.push(r.split('\t'));}});
    //You will need to add the code for accessing the spreadsheet but once you have that then all you need is
    //sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA)
  }
}
```

And you will have to figure out how to interate through new sheets for every message.

This is your example email body.

```
Transaction Report

Start Date  15/03/1919 00:00:00
End Date    15/03/1919 23:59:59
Master Distributor  Whz Pty Ltd
Agent   All
Include Sub-Agents? Y
Service All
Supplier    All
Result Code Success
Transaction Type    All
Client  All

Client Time Name    Ref Ext Trans No    Client Id   Type    Description Result Description  Value   Margin  Balance Tax
1919-03-15 18:15:16 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47523571    249a37f1-3b49-437c-9690-dcdaf8bd    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 17:06:06 Wheezless Countries 47522756    41dfb2cf-ed30-44e1-af52-be6bc0f7    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 15:14:34 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47521605    9128f9c3-edc7-4deb-b10d-3af9276d    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 14:27:38 Wheezless Countries 47519990    11453f0c-6445-4f5e-b9f4-a5d855dc    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$500.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 13:58:15 Wheezless Countries 47519607    4d2bfeb2-9628-4c66-9475-bb2a0c11    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 13:42:01 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47519428    8338070d-6e96-46b0-ba40-3e6e1767    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 13:26:29 Wheezless Countries 47519249    a88c1ebb-ade0-4666-85d5-57fda9a3    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 12:11:51 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47519270    c52397d5-e998-498e-91be-bdb4915c    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 12:10:38 Wheezless Countries 47519266    eda61596-76ff-4975-abb8-27b11bfb    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:52:49 Wheezless Countries 47519048    bb8bafc3-bbbb-47ac-a913-42df70ce    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:52:12 Wheezless Countries 47519045    1930d74b-3716-4a04-9436-b6481f9b    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:51:19 Wheezless Countries 47519042    7fc86b09-c0fb-42b6-a8a5-6456b09c    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:50:22 Wheezless Countries 47519011    31eba6d8-f939-4227-9ecc-0da4e26b    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:26:49 Wheezless Countries 47518747    913799ea-1460-46d1-be30-060fac65    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:21:36 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47518703    74b28376-5b98-400f-9c33-56174432    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:19:02 Wheezless Countries 47518652    b47d4a3c-a405-4157-b611-a5ce022f    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:18:38 Wheezless Countries 47518646    07e8f005-e8b6-4ead-9f4d-8878298e    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 11:15:35 Wheezless Countries 47518611    46c2f566-0a92-46be-8f1f-12c5157b    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 10:56:54 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47518360    156256ce-d837-4801-babb-49662e04    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$500.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 10:41:17 Wheezless Countries 47518217    9039ae1a-f14a-4f69-b69e-f400d5b0    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 10:30:10 Wheezless Countries 47518114    9d4c9685-5f56-4b5f-9d70-f81e3406    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 10:16:06 Wheezless Countries 47518006    973d04c9-90c5-48ce-8fac-f54daec5    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 10:03:54 Wheezless Countries 47517877    c786a675-f929-4add-b51e-ceba4b3e    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 09:56:34 Wheezless Countries 47517788    cde4ff23-f514-4c94-b882-5af790dc    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 09:49:19 Wheezless Countries 47517742    24e61d21-e6db-4b99-b6af-0da023ed    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 09:48:31 Wheezless Countries 47517733    8632d332-c071-4e5f-9c62-36d823c1    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 09:42:48 Wheezless Countries 47517686    342dc09f-21b4-4110-9b7c-c40c4023    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 09:26:05 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47517527    16251586-a958-4797-8da1-a073cd92    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 08:57:14 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47517294    84fadea8-cd2f-40e8-a1a0-725f3d3a    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 08:51:06 Wheezless Countries 47517251    47d3bcd8-14af-49b9-88d0-5cd228a0    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 08:48:25 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47517225    f2baaaa7-0dc0-4be3-9a16-a3421a92    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$500.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 08:22:09 Wheezless Countries 47517062    7a328bda-6cfb-4e84-9d61-d79d6bba    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 08:17:13 Wheezless Countries 47517011    370aff11-0989-4a44-90d7-b170d0f9    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 08:15:11 Wheezless Countries 47516997    3e7aec81-d583-4039-8658-409f1fdf    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:56:07 Wheezless Countries 47516881    e9fd4322-7da7-4d0f-b41f-346f9ec9    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:56:03 Wheezless Countries 47516879    0a6eea97-99b0-4640-b1eb-42df156f    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:41:27 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47516771    6c378a31-f45d-4a93-8d9b-872e2a32    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:35:26 Wheezless Countries 47516752    e5ca6944-fda9-438b-bcfc-4f492135    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:30:05 Wheezless Countries 47516714    419945ce-978a-4425-9719-90604c95    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:06:12 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47508847    1c3a30a6-3651-42dd-9f98-f1719705    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 07:05:01 Wheezless Countries 47508374    ef031fa4-5442-4935-9455-c64e6a29    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:58:32 Wheezless Countries 47505651    7179acd5-6dfe-4310-8243-d83c8426    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:38:31 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47497552    be7abe84-1de9-4080-a543-5cd45e7a    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$500.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:26:24 Wheezless Countries 47492692    fcb6e3d8-6343-468d-ba16-13b0bdcb    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:26:15 Wheezless Countries 47492630    5af2ea51-1c8f-43ec-a3df-50218190    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:23:46 Wheezless Countries 47492409    194bf5d9-618e-451c-8ccd-3af9362c    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:19:31 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492389    c3c3f185-672b-4aa7-ba97-4452a480    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:19:13 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492380    6af3edee-89e6-4419-beaf-ffcc75c8    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:15:32 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492364    47c58d04-a1ce-4de8-a076-e138c312    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:14:25 Wheezless Countries 47492351    d2c8686a-905c-456e-9c45-6070a0db    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 06:10:48 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492319    3a808d99-5e61-4252-a62d-064d19c1    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:54:21 Wheezless Countries 47492258    f896de2f-990b-42b3-9584-5e65ebd3    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:54:00 Wheezless Countries 47492254    6fbf3166-dd78-4f41-9490-17602778    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:45:43 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492196    c5b90bb6-b798-453e-91a3-629421c1    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:42:59 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492190    73ff55e5-23c1-418f-b268-38f28125    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:39:15 Wheezless Countries 47492172    e21e60e0-08f8-4639-908a-31ad0160    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:38:29 Wheezless Countries 47492160    8195a227-6479-4e41-ad93-3c87afa2    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:24:32 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47492108    43c05395-3341-4791-8433-26e5b603    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:22:33 Wheezless Countries 47492105    2a236ccf-10f7-40bc-903e-7c09f5be    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:12:05 Wheezless Countries 47491959    27a7c1b5-d367-4146-9f58-bc34294d    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 05:09:29 Wheezless Countries 47491957    f9bde37d-dec5-4c66-ae5d-3f84bfc3    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:52:22 Wheezless Countries 47491998    12d192cd-e4f9-4299-b1a0-c97f0073    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:39:15 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491938    ac473edb-150a-41ec-ba31-ea155701    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:37:57 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491928    e6c2ca24-ae51-42ee-9e7f-87ed6042    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:29:29 Wheezless Countries 47491896    a12dafd8-c47f-4609-834b-a6e79317    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:14:03 Wheezless Countries 47491844    3f0f7054-7cf4-489d-96fb-9f6683aa    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:12:38 Wheezless Countries 47491838    a64d2a86-6b13-4826-95c5-8cf54e28    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:03:28 Wheezless Countries 47491791    c0b580e7-ab7b-4ebe-858f-53197025    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:02:51 Wheezless Countries 47491780    3d78a58c-eadc-4b5c-8e6a-1980b844    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$190.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:02:49 Wheezless Countries 47491778    c501d38d-c51c-4591-aafa-351faf05    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:01:45 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491773    e0a9136e-9c13-48e0-97b3-f74b772d    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:01:37 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491767    e326f3a3-e1aa-4717-b195-e9bdb0b3    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:01:01 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491765    e6a82b4d-ffbd-47db-baa7-1ada78ae    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 04:00:24 Wheezless Countries 47491761    92fd9f90-63a9-4a51-b8af-4a590879    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 03:32:40 Wheezless Countries 47491617    68a9fa6f-cb63-4d91-ac9b-a33dfa98    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 03:29:29 Wheezless Countries 47491612    87e784f6-1683-4895-9acc-62ae260b    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 03:17:03 Wheezless Countries 47491557    3e906850-ea33-498a-9fca-70319d5b    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 03:12:40 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491519    aba28f9c-68a4-449f-8403-2b8d3eec    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 03:03:31 Wheezless Countries 47491489    c04c25a3-e53f-4c35-915c-4902a333    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 02:47:04 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491414    dd272833-196b-4a93-a314-a92f801e    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 02:24:49 Wheezless Countries 47491327    e1ff3d97-58ec-4470-99f3-b3e0bec5    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 02:22:58 Wheezless Countries 47491319    d5f33ba0-9475-424c-84b3-36f3d08f    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 02:19:08 Wheezless Countries 47491303    5fab2744-7705-4383-a3e5-2a4d1e34    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 02:06:34 Wheezless Countries 47491238    5214a242-3f59-46fe-839d-8156c188    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 02:00:40 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491215    24cebe15-858d-49ca-9340-1b694476    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:59:55 Wheezless Countries 47491213    a1f108e6-d8ca-41eb-95f0-7ec723ab    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:56:34 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491192    453bdfdb-d3aa-48f4-89de-8deb49d1    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:54:08 Wheezless Countries 47491181    a2abba31-084c-424c-bb66-07da487c    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:52:37 Wheezless Countries 47491175    cc26a13c-d160-42fa-a96f-feee2652    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:47:12 Wheezless Countries 47491145    07193e6f-6f53-41d6-b046-97b7deea    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:43:27 Wheezless Countries 47491102    453fcc7f-92dd-4770-a5a0-0f5e3ccd    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:21:18 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47491004    4cf007a7-0ea5-41ad-9adb-0557dd12    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$30.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:19:30 Neon.com.tn Pty Ltd 47490991    08ef9479-e8c9-43d4-9c02-5ff0b6ab    NeonFL2349FWEG34    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:12:13 Wheezless Countries 47490955    64b974d2-e236-4d6d-893f-ae19caa3    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 01:11:43 Wheezless Countries 47490950    e066a97a-b070-47b2-a6df-3030919c    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$300.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 00:47:33 Wheezless Countries 47490847    1a36f8aa-a1f6-4b35-ab6a-e6fad072    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$100.00    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 00:33:02 Wheezless Countries 47490804    d55ca1e8-14f6-448d-b77b-73991318    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$50.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
1919-03-15 00:08:30 Wheezless Countries 47490718    d2500ac2-dcb0-4846-8bd5-dc2b940a    LQOSBFZDZIEBCASA    Rdem    Redemption  Success -$19.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
Total   -$9,750.00  $0.00       $0.00
Generated On:Mon, 16 Mar 1919 16:19:19 +1100    Processing time: 0.036 Seconds
End of Transaction Report
transactionSummary v1.28
```

Comment: I can get this by manually copying. Script can't get this text body, instead it gets it in html format.