# gsheet Script works in editor, not on a button or menu

Tags: google-apps-script, button

I copied a script to pull certain emails and put them in a spreadsheet. The script works fine if run in editor but does not write the emails if I run with a button (drawing) or menu item. The pop up indicates the script is running and about half the time, the emails are marked as read (as written in the script), but the info is never written to the sheet unless run from editor. I would prefer only the button but tried the menu only as a workaround.

The original script did not have `SpreadsheetApp` line in `saveEmails`. I added because I would like to run the script on open and calling the function from onOpen wasn't working so I ditched that and added a trigger. Needed to add the SpreadsheetApp line to get it to work. Tried adding it to the other functions but it didn't help.

I did find info that with the global variable, `onOpen` needs to be listed before the variable, but that didn't seem to help getting the button to work.
Code is below. Only changed the personal data.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu("My Menu")
        .addItem("Update","saveEmails")
        .addToUi();
}
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:TeacherLog is:unread from:username@mydomain.com newer_than:1d ";

// Credit: Alexander Ivanov
// https://gist.github.com/contributorpw/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708
// https://www.labnol.org/code/20053-save-gmail-to-google-spreadsheet


function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([
                msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*/gm, ''),
                msgs[j].getSubject(),
                msgs[j].markRead()
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    //if there are no emails to log, don't run 
    if (array2d.length == 0){}
    else {
        sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
    }
}

function saveEmails() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated. Just want people to be able to click on a button and pull any new emails.

Comment: Hey there. I tried to fix up the formatting on your code block. You can either surround your code in three backticks (`\`\`\`code\`\`\``) or put four spaces before each line. Alternatively, selecting your code and pressing Ctrl+K should do the trick as well. Also, you don't need `<BR>`; if you put two spaces at the end of a line, or just add an extra blank line, it will space our your paragraphs.

Comment: For some reason, when I copied your script & replicated on my end, it works fine (the emails & their subjects were added on the sheet) when clicking the `My Menu` > `Update` (I only changed the `SEARCH_QUERY` to search & save emails from my test account).

Comment: @hyper-neutrino THANKS SO MUCH for making it nicer. I will remember CTRL-K.

Comment: @IrvinJayG.  Thanks for trying. I cannot get it actually work properly still. This is where I get really frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion

You can try this script below that's simpler & doesn't contain multiple functions:

### Script:

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:done from:mail-noreply@google.com "; //Edit it to your actual query

function saveEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search(SEARCH_QUERY);

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var html = messages[j].getBody();
      var msg = getTextFromHtml(html);
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      ss.appendRow([msg, sub]);
      messages[j].markRead();
    }
  }
}

function getTextFromHtml(html) { //Function to clean the body of the email & save it in pure text form
  html=html.replace(/<\/div>/ig, '\n');
  html=html.replace(/<\/li>/ig, '\n');
  html=html.replace(/<li>/ig, '  *');
  html=html.replace(/<\/ul>/ig, '\n');
  html=html.replace(/<\/p>/ig, '\n');
  html=html.replace(/<br\/?>/ig, '\n');
  html=html.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, '');
  return html;
}
```

> Note: I ave used some code from an answer at [Google Apps Scripts - Extract data from gmail into a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32897768) as reference.

### Test Result:

1. Assigned the `saveEmails` function to a button on a test sheet:

---

> [image]

2. Sample emails to be added on sheet:

---

> [image]

3. The sheet after clicking the button:

---

> [image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Will give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: THANKS! That did enough of the trick. The button still only wants to mark them read and not import them, but it works from the menu so I'll live with that!