# Automatically update a Google sheet based on Gmail emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet with different rows: *Name *Email *Gmail Label

How to make them(name, email, label) update/add automatically to sheets from Gmail?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This link could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890847/google-apps-scripts-extract-data-from-gmail-into-a-spreadsheet