# Method to exclude inline replies from GMail messages using Google Apps Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps

I have a rather large script running several functions that I use to automate my billing process. One of the facets of the script is applying a words per minute calculation on sent and received email messages to estimate the time spent. This works great on single email messages. However, replies throw this out of whack. In cases where there are dozens of replies/messages in a single thread I can end up with a 5,000+ word message when the actual email I'm trying to process is a single sentence.

Currently what I'm using to try to isolate the new method seems pretty clumsy. I grab the entire message body as a string and then pass it to the function I've pasted below. I then use a regex to try to find the end of the first message based on both text and markup that is commonly found at or near the end of email messages I receive. I then try to clean up formatting to get an accurate word count for the most recent message.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      EMAILS  --  ISOLATE THE NEW MESSAGE &
//                  IGNORE INCLUDED FORWARDS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
function email_IsolateNewMessage(messageString) {
  var bodyCleaned = [],
      bodyTRIM, length, newMessage;
  var minMsgLength = 10;

  var regex = /<div\sclass\=\"gmail\_quote\"\>|On .*20[0-9]{2}.*@.*\..*wrote\:|-\s?Original\sMessage\s?-|<div\slang="EN-US"[^>]*?>|Confidentiality Notice<\/span>|\"signature image\"/ig; // changed slightly to be "non-greedy" to try to avoid timeouts.

  bodyTRIM = messageString.split(regex);
  length = bodyTRIM.length;

  for (var i=0; i < bodyTRIM.length; ++i){
    //remove line breaks
    bodyTRIM[i] = bodyTRIM[i].replace(/\n/g,"");
    //remove html
    bodyTRIM[i] = bodyTRIM[i].replace(/<\/?\s?(div|br|span|strong|em|img|p|u|b|font)[^>]*>/ig," ");
  }

  for (var i=0; i < bodyTRIM.length; ++i){
    if (bodyTRIM[i].length > minMsgLength){
      newMessage = bodyTRIM[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (typeof newMessage == 'undefined') {
     var newMessage = "";
     var nml = newMessage.split(" ").length;
  }
  return newMessage;
}
```

The regex is entirely hit-and-miss. Obviously there's no standard email signature format and sometimes people don't use signatures at all.

I'm curious if anyone else has any ideas for this? 
Gmail seems to have a pretty good method for doing this since the replied messages are hidden by the "show trimmed content" dots. However, in spite of much time googling, I could only find folks trying methods to get Gmail to IGNORE the repeated content, not emulate that behavior. Gmail does not seem to insert anything into the message itself at the "trimmed content" location, so my thought is it must be pulling *something* from the message formatting... like I said... this has been a dead-end for me.

So, my question: Does anyone have any ideas of a better method or an improvement to my script that might make it find JUST the newest message text more reliably?  Thanks.

**EDIT:** I came up with the following which is still not ideal, but seems to work a little bit better. Basically, instead of looking at one message at a time, it works through the thread comparing previous messages. If the first 200 characters of a previous msg are in the body of the current message, it cuts the current message at that point. This works, but still feels incredibly clumsy though... (Ignore the wordCount stuff, that's garbage).

```
function email_IsolateNewMessage2(threadId) {
  var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(GmailApp.getThreadById(threadId));
  var arr = [];
  var wordCount = 0;

  for (var i=0; i!=msgs.length; ++i){
    var msgDate = msgs[i].getDate();
    var msgBody = msgs[i].getBody();
    var length  = msgBody.length;

    var thisMsgLength = length-wordCount;
    var wordCount = wordCount + length;

    arr.push([msgDate, msgBody, length, thisMsgLength]);

    var newArrLength = arr.length
    for (var j=0; j!=arr.length; ++j){
      var source = arr[j][1];
      var compare = arr[i][1];
      if (arr[j][1].indexOf(arr[j][1].slice(0,200)) > -1 && arr[j] != arr[i]){
        var cutLocation = arr[i][1].indexOf(arr[j][1].slice(0,200));
        arr[i][1] = arr[i][1].slice(0,cutLocation);
        arr[i][4] = arr[i][1].length;
      }
    }
  }
  debugger;
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Apparently this has been a previous post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304684/google-apps-script-gmail-get-message-without-previous-conversation?rq=1 Not sure how I missed that. However, that is relying on reading and writing from spreadsheets, whereas I have no sheet.