# Google Script: get content of an email answer without the original email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am having troubles dealing with the emails that are answers to emails I sent myself. Indeed, when I use the method 'getPlainBody' to get the content of the email, I always get a text containing the message I want AND my original message. Moreover, the format is never the same, depending on the email client of the other person, I guess.

Some examples to illustrate this:

```
Hello,
This is my answer to your email.
Best regards

On Wed, Jul 12, 2017 at 10:02 AM, Bastien <bastien@example.org> wrote:

> Hi,
>
> This is the original email I sent you.
> Bastien
```

Or this:

```
Hello,
This is my answer to your email.
Best regards


From: bastien@example.org [mailto:bastien@example.org]
Sent: Wednesday, July 12, 2017 6:49 PM
To: someone <someone@example.com>
Subject: this is the original subject

Hi,

This is the original email I sent you.
Bastien
```

I would like to retrieve only this part:

```
Hello,
This is my answer to your email.
Best regards
```

I also have emails many different languages, so the information separating the original message and the answer can be written in any language, so it is a bit complicated to detect it programmatically for any language.

I am sure Gmail knows how to do that, because in the Gmail interface it only shows the part of the email that I want, and automatically hides my first email. I just do not know if there is a way to extract the message using Google Script.

Comment: Instead of get the plain body, why don't you get the [raw content](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getRawContent()) ? You may find some answers with the HTML structure of the mail, like Gmail may do ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to have a look at the raw content, but is not easily really readable for me... There is a huge header that gives a lot of information about email servers, authentication, dkim signatures, smtp messages that I do not really understand, etc... And then there is the exact same text I get with the 'getPlainBody'. I'm not sure of how I should use all the data found in the header, do you know what I should be looking for ?

Comment: Gmail knows how to do this because it has the entire chain of emails. It hides the part that matches earlier messages. Sometimes, when you get two messages with identical content, the second one will have its body hidden even though it's not a reply.

Comment: Try the workaround given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304684/google-apps-script-gmail-get-message-without-previous-conversation?rq=1). However, this relies in reading and writing from spreadsheets. See if it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Bastien,

I did resolve in a not elegant but fairly stable way getting the body and taking advantage of the *Gmail knows* situation, i.e. looking for the tag *`<div class="gmail_quote">`* which is the `[...]` showed by GMail.

In those cases where `[...]` *is not the case* (e.g. mail sent by microsoft mail) the first *`<div>`* sometimes do the trick. 
You will see two others attempts harvested on errors saw since the first implementation of this code (about a year ago). In my case the *senders universe* is quite small so this cheesy solution works nice.
Good luck.

```
mRtaU = mails[j].getBody();

  mRta = mRtaU;

  mRta = mRta.substring(0,mRta.toLowerCase().indexOf('<div class="gmail_quote">'));  

  if( mRta == '' ){ 
    mRta = mRtaU;
    if( mRta.slice( 0, 5 ) == '<div>' ){ //case Microsoft try I...

      mRta = mRta.substring(0,mRta.toLowerCase().indexOf('</div>'));
    }else{

      if( mRta.slice( 0, 2 ) == '<p' ){ //case Microsoft try II...

        mRta = mRta.substring(0, mRta.toLowerCase().indexOf('</p>')); 
      }else{

        mRta = mRta.substring(0,mRta.indexOf('\n')); //last try, a crlf could split the answer from original (yeap, no crlf in html but...)
      }
    }
  }
  mRta = mRta.split('<br>').join('\n').replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```