# Google Apps Script Google Sheets Gmail Processing New Emails Append Row Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm taking emails from gmail, parsing them using jquery, then I want to send the scraped data from each email into its own row in the google sheet. I have the code working up to the point where I have the necessary data scraped, and I push it into an array. Then I want to check for duplicates if there are any matches in the existing google sheet rows and if not then put the data into rows in the sheet.

I used the following post as a model for the array part but can't get what he did to work for my data:
[Google script is reprocessing emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835814/google-script-is-reprocessing-emails?rq=1)

I'd appreciate any insights into getting the array to dump into the sheet. The unique value I'll be using to check for duplicates would be the person's name (var name) which is column 3 in the spreadsheet

```
function appendLead() {
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZDKMISf8Hbw7ERfP6h-Q0pztQSMqsN-mHfeM3E_Ywg/edit#gid=0';
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var leadsData = ss.getSheetByName('Leads Data');
    var myLabel = "Buyer Inquiries/1. To Process"; // Name of current label being processed, this label is set via a filter in Gmail
    var newLabel = "Buyer Inquiries/2. Processed"; // Name of "New" filter, this label needs to be created in Gmail first
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(myLabel);
    var label2 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(newLabel);
    var threads = label.getThreads();
    var data2 = [];
    var newData = [];
  
    for (var i = 0; i< threads.length; i++) {
      var message = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i])[0];
      
    
      // move thread from label to label2
      label2.addToThread(threads[i]);
      label.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
      
      var messageBodyhtml = message.getBody()
      
      var $ = Cheerio.load(messageBodyhtml);
      var date = $('span:contains("Date:")').siblings('span').text().trim();
      var property = $('span:contains("Regarding:")').siblings('span').text().trim();
      var name = $('span:contains("From:")').first().siblings('span').text().trim();
      var phone = $('span:contains("Contact Information:")').siblings('span').children().first().text().trim();
      var email = $('span:contains("Contact Information:")').siblings('span').children().last().text().trim();
      var comments = $('span:contains("Comments:")').siblings('span').text().trim();
      var source = $('span:contains("Lead From:")').siblings('span').text().trim();
  
      var array = [date,property,name,phone,email,comments,source]
      Logger.log(array);
      data2.push([array[i]]);
    }
    // Compare the information in the data2 array to existing information in the sheet
    var data = leadsData.getRange("A2:G").getValues(); //Change this to fit your data ranges
    for(i in data2){
      var row = data2[i];
      var duplicate = false;
      for(j in data){
        if(row.join() == data[j].join()){
          duplicate = true;
        }
      }
      if(!duplicate){
        newData.push(row);
      }
    }
    if (newData.length){  // runs the below code only if there is newData, this stops an error when newData is empty
      leadsData.getRange(leadsData.getLastRow()+1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData); //writes newData to end of sheet
    }
}
```

This is the result on the sheet after running - only the first array segment pastes on the sheet - and it's not pasted in as a row - it's pasted in down one column

```
10/19/2020 9:51:16 AM
address
Sandra

email@gmail.com
ACTION: Tour Request 10/03/2020 10:00AM   
Source website
```

I can't get the duplicate checker portion to work (e.g. if the row already exists, and I process the same email again as a test, the info gets appended as a row in the spreadsheet even if it's a duplicate)

```
var data = leadsData.getRange("A2:G").getValues(); //Change this to fit your data ranges
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var duplicate = false;
      data2.forEach(function(row2) {
        if (row.join() == row2.join()) {
          duplicate = true;
        }
      });
      if (!duplicate) {
        newData.push(row);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Define `but can't get what he did to work for my data` - what is the issue?

Comment: I can see in the console log that up to line `data2.push([array[i]])` everything is going to the array correctly. The part after that I want to check for duplicates by comparing the array of new data to the already existing data to see if there are duplicates. If a row of data is not a duplicate, push it from array data2 to newArray. Then append the newArray rows to the sheet (using setValues not using appendRow). It's this bottom part to check duplicates and paste the array to the sheet that's not pasting any data. Only the first array pastes - and not as a row - see edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The array structure for setting values to a Spreadsheet range is `Array[rows][columns]`.*

#### Structural Information:

Let's say you want to insert two rows of data to a sheet using `.setValues()`.

The data for row 1 is 8 cells in length, each cell being a value from v1-v8.
The data for row 2 is also 8 cells in length, but only columns A, B, G and H have data.

The array structure should be as follows:

```
var arr = [
            ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8"], // row 1
            ["A-v", "B-v", "", "", "", "", "G-v", "H-v"]      // row 2
          ];
```

And this will need to be set with:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpredsheet()
              .getSheetByName("Sheet-name")
              .getRange("A1:B8")
              .setValues(arr);
```

This will appear in the Sheet as:

```
         |    A   |    B   |    C   |    D   |    E   |    F   |    G   |    H   |    
=========+========+========+========+========+========+========+========+========+
    1    |   v1   |   v2   |   v3   |   v4   |   v5   |   v6   |   v7   |   v8   |
---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    2    |   A-v  |  B-v   |        |        |        |        |  G-v   |  H-v   |
---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    3    |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    4    |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |        |
---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

#### Code-specific Fix:

Use a nested `forEach()` instead of `for... in`:

```
data.forEach(function(row) {
  var duplicate = false;
  data2.forEach(function(row2) {
    if (row.join() == row2.join()) {
      duplicate = true;
    }
  });
  if (!duplicate) {
    newData.push(row);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out the problem: I changed `data2.push([array[i]])` to `data2.push(array)` and it created the array correctly and the values paste to the sheet correctly now

Comment: Can you please explain how changing what you log changed the structure of the Array?

Comment: It was a paste error - not log but the push. The [array[i]] was just making [[1a],[1a,2a],[1a,2a,3a]...to 26 places] and that was only for the first row (a is the lead). The correct output array is now like [1a,2a,3a,4a,5a,6a,7a],[1b,2b,3b,4b,5b,6b,7b],... where a pastes to one row, and b pastes to the second row, etc. It works now

Comment: @823g4n8901 That's what I'd thought, glad to hear it's working now. Consider accepting the answer if you think it'll help others with the same problem on the future

Comment: Thanks for the update on the duplicate checker. I have the following code in the script but now it's not putting any rows onto the sheet when run (please see what I've added in the above edit). I think what I need to have it do is make an array of the existing sheet rows. If a row matches the new data array then don't push that new data to the sheet. e.g. if a row in the sheet is ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8"] and the new array contains a row with ["v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8"] then don't paste that to the sheet as it's a duplicate