# Removing html tags and content where tag content matches an array of values using Xml.parse()

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, google-apps-script

I've extracted some html from GmailApp using .getBody() and would like to return some html which filters a specific tag and contents where the contents matches any value in an array (specifically links with certain text). Looking at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312588/1027723) I figure the easiest way to do this would be to use `Xml.parse()` and filter the object but can't get beyond creating the XmlDocument.

For example, if:

```
var html = '<div>some text then <div><a href="http://example1.com">foo</a></div> and then <span>some <a href="http://example2.com">baa</a>,and finally <a href="http://example3.com">close</a></span></div>';
```

and

```
var linksToRemove = ['baa','foo'];
```

how could I return

```
var newHtml = '<div>some text then <div></div> and then <span>some ,and finally <a href="http://example3.com">close</a></span></div>';
```

using

```
var obj = Xml.parse(html, true);
```

I can get an object to process but it all falls apart from there (I did also consider just using `.replace()` but given the issues with matching  with RegEx thought it best to avoid)

Comment: There is the unwritten rule of not parsing html with regex, but in this instance (which is a simple find and replace) it is the method I would use. XML.parse assumes a well formed XML document. HTML often is not, despite best intentions.

Comment: @Jonathon problem I had when doing this was replace was okay on hardcoded test data but failed with .getBody() html. My basic test regex was `html.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>(Manage your subscriptions)<\/a>/ig,"");` Does .getBody return escaped html?

Comment: @Jonathon found the issue there was a carriage break in the getBody() response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following suggestion opted to try using regex

```
var html = '<div>some text then <div><a href="http://example1.com">foo</a></div> and then <span>some <a href="http://example2.com">baa</a>,and finally <a href="http://example3.com">close</a></span></div>';

var linksToRemove = ['baa', 'foo'];
var newHtml = cleanBody(html, linksToRemove);

/**
 * Removes links from html text
 * @param {string} html The html to be cleaned.
 * @param {array} exclude The array of link text to remove.
 * @returns {string} Cleaned html.
 */
function cleanBody(html, exclude) {
    html = html.replace(/\r?\n|\r|\t/g, ''); // used to remove breaks and tabs
    var re = '<a\\b[^>]*>(' + exclude.join('|') + ')<\\/a>';
    return html.replace(new RegExp(re, 'ig'), "");
}
```

Test at http://jsfiddle.net/HdsPU/

Comment: If you have a specific need with a format that you more or less know or better still control, regex works well. If you were looking to build a browser it would be one of the worst ways of doing things :D