# Grabbing Text from HTML Font using Google Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have the following HTML codes and would like to use Google Script to obtain 39.85 and 2.49*.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <font size="4" color="#000000" >Malaysia RM </font>
  </td>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <font size="4" color="#000000" >39.85</font>
  </td>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" >
    <font size="4" color="#000000" >2.49*</font>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I uses following Google Scripts but got back 0.

```
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://.......');
var pageHTML = page.getContentText();
var xml = Xml.parse(pageHTML, true);
var mainTable = xml.getElement("body").getElement("table").getElement("tr");
var buy = mainTable.getElements("td")[1].getText();
var sell = mainTable.getElements("td")[2].getText();
```

I found the desired texts are bounded by font inside each td. Is there any API to get around this font section and retrieve the text.

Answer (score 0):

I use this general purpose function [from this answer (Corey G)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936092/remove-formatting-tags-from-string-body-of-email/11312588#11312588) to get Text from html and it works flawlessly.

```
function getTextFromHtml(html) {
  return getTextFromNode(Xml.parse(html, true).getElement());
}


function getTextFromNode(x) {
  switch(x.toString()) {
    case 'XmlText': return x.toXmlString();
    case 'XmlElement': return x.getNodes().map(getTextFromNode).join('');
    default: return '';
  }
}


function test(){
  var xx='<table><tr><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><font size="4" color="#000000" >Malaysia RM </font></td><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><font size="4" color="#000000" >39.85</font></td><td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" ><font size="4" color="#000000" >2.49*</font></td></tr></table>'
Logger.log(getTextFromHtml(xx))
}

// Log result : [13-07-16 08:50:52:942 CEST] Malaysia RM 39.852.49*
```

From there a few simple string operations would allow you to retrieve the values you want (using dots as markers for example).